# Single-electron propagator in disordered media: higher moments?

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, disorder, anderson-localization

The known result that the impurity-averaged single electron propagator takes the form

$ \langle G_0(r) \rangle \sim e^{-|r|/\ell} $, for $\ell$ the mean free path

is frequently quoted by papers on the subject of disordered electronic materials. I was wondering if there are results concerning the higher moments (or if there are any known distributions), and how these depend on $r$, material quantities, external fields, etc. For example, I would expect that the variance of $G_0$ would fall off as a function of $|r|/\ell$. If anyone has sources that shed light on this, I would appreciate it!